# using jscolor.js after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

if I want to use jscolor.js in HTML or in jquery function but it does not work after button click

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
 
   
      $('#click').click(function () {
           
                $("#placeholder").html("<input class=jscolor value=714BAB>"); 
       });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="jscolor" value="714BAB">
 <div id="placeholder"></div>
 <button id="click">click</button>
```

it works in html but does not after button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

What I have done is re initialize the jscolor by adding `jscolor.installByClassName("jscolor");`

Run the snippet and see for yourself.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#click').click(function () {
        
        $("#placeholder").html("<input class='jscolor' value='714BAB'>"); 
        jscolor.installByClassName("jscolor");
       });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.js"></script>
Color: <input class="jscolor" value="714BAB">
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
    <button id="click">click</button>
```

Comment: @omarabdelkefi If this answer fully answers your question please accept the answer so we can see you don't need help anymore.

Comment: @Mark Baijens this is the first time I post a question  how can I accept the answer

Comment: @omarabdelkefi Click on the "V" on the left of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the element and append it dynamicly like this. You can use the fromString method to set the right color.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#click').click(function() {
    var input = document.createElement('INPUT');
    var picker = new jscolor(input);
    picker.fromString('714BAB');
    $("#placeholder").empty().append(input);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.js"></script>
Color: <input class="jscolor" value="714BAB">
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<button id="click">click</button>
```